# event.preventDefault does not work in Android 4.4.4

Tags: android, keydown

When trying to prevent the space bar to be entered inside a password field (input type="password" no-space) on Android 4.4.4 it does not prevent the key being pressed. In Android 4.4.2 it works fine. I also tried the same using emulator on 4.4.2 (and device) and that works also.

```
    element.bind("keydown", function(e){
     if (e.keyCode === 32 ){
     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopPropagation();
    }
```

Is this a bug in 4.4.4? And how can it be solved?

Answer (score 0):

I was mistaken on my previous answer so i'll just explain one of the ways i'd implement it, which may work.

```
<input type="text" ng-keydown="disableSpaces($event)">
<script>
    function ctrl($scope){
        $scope.disableSpaces = function($event){
            if($event.keyCode === 32) $event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks I will try this but i don't see the difference except you are using ng-keydown event which I'm doing in directive <input..no-space> .. Can you explain?

Comment: I don't know if it will work, but the ng-whatever directives have boilerplate code under the hood so that we don't have to implement it. If you fall back to bind the event manually through a directive, you must implement that boilerplate by yourself.

Maybe and just maybe there is something inside the ng-keydown event that could make it work even though your code was in fact correct.